# How to stub an external API for testing

Tags: testing, node.js, stubbing

I have a project that makes some calls to Twitter's API from the node.js server that I would like to test. However, I don't want to test the Twitter API (OAuth and the actual API I'm calling), so I thought it would be best to stub it out.

I found sinon.js that supports this supposedly. I have not found an example of how to do this and was wondering if this has been done before. And if so, seeing some sample code would really help.

Comment: I already marked an answer as accepted, but just thought I'd put this out there. I wrote a blog post using Sinon to stub the object for the Twitter API. If anyone is interested in seeing how it works with Sinon, take a look at it. http://blog.thejon.org/post/7841628779/stubbing-restful-apis-in-a-node-js-project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you doing to call the API?

Imagine you use a method called `api.call('url', function (error, response) {...})`:

you can "fake" the callback with sinon, gently or whatever you like.

Example using gently:

```
gently.expect(api, 'call', function (url, callback) {
  assert.equal(url, 'http://api.twitter.com/...');
  callback(Error('Fake error'), null);
});
```

Comment: So if I wanted to return some fake JSON, then callback(null, {id: 1}); would work?

Comment: yes! Check those tests for instance, I test the error case and the returning json case too: https://github.com/masylum/dialect/blob/master/test/stores/mongodb.js#L59